# WHMCS hook pass variables to shell script

Tags: php, shell, hook, whmcs

I need to pass 2 variables from a WHMCS PHP hook script to another shell script as follows : (variables are `$domain` and `$email` )

```
$output = shell_exec('/scripts/clone-wp2.sh $Email $domain');
```

The script get executed but the variables are not passed to the shell although they have values,in /scripts/clone-wp2.sh $1 and $2 have null values.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes, like this:

```
$output = shell_exec("/scripts/clone-wp2.sh $Email $domain");
```

As per the documentation, you can't use inline-variables with single-quotes.

*Source*:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing